# OpenCv imwrite doesn't work because of special character in file path

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I can't save an image when the file path has special character (like "é" for example).

Here is a test from Python 3 shell :

```
>>> cv2.imwrite('gel/test.jpg', frame)
True
>>> cv2.imwrite('gel/ééé/test.jpg', frame)
False
>>> cv2.imwrite('gel/eee/test.jpg', frame)
True
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

Unfortunately, all suggestions proposed by @PM2Ring and @DamianLattenero don't seem to work :(

So, I use the @cdarke's solution, here's my final code :

```
destination = 'gel/ééé/'
gel = 'test.jpg'
script_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(destination)
cv2.imwrite(gel, frame)
os.chdir(script_path)
```

Comment: Which OS? Did you try `cv2.imwrite('gel/ééé/test.jpg'.encode(), frame)` ?

Comment: Windows 10 (with Python 3.6.1)
I tried, It still doesn't seem to work...
`TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation` and when I print : `b'gel/\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9/test.jpg'`

Comment: Since the non-ASCII characters are in a directory name, maybe you could `os.chdir('gel/ééé')` then just use `cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', frame)`?  Its nasty and ugly, but should work.

Comment: @cdarke Yep, it's working! Thanks but if I can find a "cleaner" solution, that would be better!

Comment: Ah, Windows. In that case, I think you need `.encode('UTF-16LE')`

Comment: I got again the same error `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`
(and the print : `b'g\x00e\x00l\x00/\x00\xe9\x00\xe9\x00\xe9\x00/\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00.\x00j\x00p\x00g\x00'`

Comment: Drats. Allegedly, Windows does use a form of UTF-16 for Unicode filenames, but it looks like you need to pass the UTF-16 directly to the Windows system calls that handle that stuff, and I don't know how the Python / Windows interface handles that sort of thing.

Comment: It's weird that you're having problems, though. In Python 3, all normal text strings are Unicode, so you shouldn't need to do any encoding: any function that expects a text string should work correctly whether that string contains plain ASCII chars or more exotic Unicode stuff. But maybe `cv2` is doing something strange.

Comment: Yep... I think the problem come from `cv2`, I have a lot of other special characters in my script and I never had that kind of issue.

Comment: Maybe you should submit a bug report to the `cv2` guys.  I doubt that it is a python/Windows issue since `os.chdir()` works OK.

Comment: chdir solved this for unicode chars in folder name. But what if there are unicode chars in the file name?

Answer (score 9):

You can first encode the image with OpenCV and then save it with numpy `tofile()` method since the encoded image is a one-dim numpy ndarray：

```
is_success, im_buf_arr = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)

im_buf_arr.tofile('gel/ééé/test.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding with:

```
cv2.imwrite('gel/ééé/test.jpg'.encode('utf-8'), frame) # or just .encode(), 'utf-8' is the default
```

If you are using windows, maybe with:

```
cv2.imwrite("gel/ééé/test.jpg".encode("windows-1252"), frame)
```

Or now reading the @PM user answer, according your utf-16 windows:

```
cv2.imwrite("gel/ééé/test.jpg".encode('UTF-16LE'), frame)
```

if non of that works to you, try this:

```
ascii_printable = set(chr(i) for i in range(0x20, 0x7f))

def convert(ch):
    if ch in ascii_printable:
        return ch
    ix = ord(ch)
    if ix < 0x100:
        return '\\x%02x' % ix
    elif ix < 0x10000:
        return '\\u%04x' % ix
    return '\\U%08x' % ix

path = 'gel/ééé/test.jpg'

converted_path = ''.join(convert(ch) for ch in 'gel/ééé/test.jpg')

cv2.imwrite(converted_path, frame)
```

Comment: We already tried that. :) The default encoding used by `str.encode` is UTF-8. However, Windows uses UTF-16, and I'm pretty sure it needs to be little endian (I don't use Windows unless I can't avoid it).

Comment: @PM2Ring aaaah I get it, did you try then with .encode("windows-1252"))? I updated the answer

Comment: BTW, it would have been better to modify your old answer rather than deleting & creating a new one. You should be ok, but "the system" penalizes you if you delete stuff too often. It's ok to temporarily delete an answer while you fix it, though.

Comment: @PM2Ring penalize? how? I didn't know that, I delete things that are wrong... I didn't think that should be penalized in somewere

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't read your comment before, sorry, I finally put a good answer, or at least a correct one ahahah, thanks for all the helping :D, finally an old user with high reputation that doesn't make me feel like sh**t, thanks for the humble

Comment: I tried all your `.encode()`suggestions but none of these seem to work :(

Comment: :) Actually, I wasn't quite right about the penalty. That only happens if you delete too many negative-score answers, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110101/does-deleting-own-answers-result-in-a-penalty-too-many-or-regularly?noredirect=1&lq=1) for further info. OTOH, deleted posts aren't really deleted: any mod, or any normal user with rep >= 10000 can see them.

Comment: @PM2Ring :O I didn't knew that, all my ashamed answer are there to them to laugth, so sad ahahahahha

Comment: @TeeVy try the updated answer, if that doesn't work, none in this world would :P, if the answer was useful dont forget to accept the answer with the (✓) left the answer and vote now you can :D

Comment: @DamianLattenero Unfortunately, this still not working... :(
Thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

In one line.

`cv2.imencode(".jpg",frame)[1].tofile("gel/ééé/test.jpg")`

Answer (score 2):

These are my functions for both writing and reading:

```py
def read_image(path):
    return cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(path,dtype=np.uint8), -1)

def save_image(img, path):
    cv2.imencode(".png", img)[1].tofile(path+'/your_file_name.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding issues.... difficult but no impossible

if you have this string = `'テスト/abc.jpg'`

**You can encode as Windows encoding the characters like this**->

`print('テスト/abc.jpg'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))`

And you get something like this = `'ãã¹ã/abc.jpg'`

**Then if you want to read the file and get the filenames readable and usable, you can use some library to read the filenames of your path and then change the encoding**->

`#fname is like 'ãã¹ã/abc.jpg'`

`fname.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8'))` # This result of your initial string =`'テスト/abc.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img_encoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg",frame)[1]
with open("ééé/test.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img_encoded)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).