# Python Opencv imwrite with Turkish Characters

Tags: python, opencv

When I define the filename with the Turkish character in the code below, the code doesn't work. How can I fix this problem? (I'm using Win10 and Python 3.7)

```
cv2.imwrite('./Atatürk İlkokulu/img1.jpg', yeni_boyut)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCv imwrite doesn't work because of special character in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330084/opencv-imwrite-doesnt-work-because-of-special-character-in-file-path)

Comment: os.chdir('./Atatürk İlkokulu/') After this code I got the error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: How does that relate to the rest of the question so far?

Comment: Excuse me, it's my fault. I fixed it

Comment: folder = 'Atatürk İlkokulu/'
        name = 'img1.jpg'
        apppath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(folder)
        cv2.imwrite(name, yeni_boyut)
        os.chdir(apppath)